# react-pdf line tag doesn't generate horizontal line

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I'm trying to generate a resume using react-pdf. I want to draw a horizontal line under every section title but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm following [this](https://react-pdf.org/repl?example=line) example from the docs

```
const Resume = () => {
  const info = {
    name: "James Bond",
    email: "007@gmail.com",
    phone: "+65 12345678",
  };

  return (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
        <View style={styles.title}>
          <Text>{info.name}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.subtitle}>
          <Text>
            {info.email} | {info.phone}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Svg height="500" width="500">
          <Line
            x1="0"
            y1="200"
            x2="200"
            y2="200"
            strokeWidth={2}
            stroke="rgb(0,0,0)"
          />
        </Svg>
        <View style={styles.sectionTitle}>
          <Text>Education</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.sectionTitle}>
          <Text>Work Experience</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.sectionTitle}>
          <Text>Skills</Text>
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};
```

React version: 18.2.0

react-pdf version: 3.1.9

Comment: your code is working fine.. Line is getting drawn

Comment: It doesn't show on my screen https://imgur.com/a/9L4QRy9

Answer (score 0):

Basically the line is needed at each position just like a < hr > in HTML.

[image]

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: { padding: 50 },
});
const info = {
    name: "James Bond",
    email: "007@gmail.com",
    phone: "+65 12345678",
  };
const doc = (
  <Document>
    <Page style={styles.page} size="A4">
       <View style={styles.title}>
          <Text>{info.name}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.subtitle}>
          <Text>
            {info.email} | {info.phone}
          </Text>
      
      <Svg height="10" width="495">
          <Line x1="0" y1="5" x2="280" y2="5" strokeWidth={2} stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" />
      </Svg>
      </View>
      
      <View style={styles.sectionTitle}><Text> </Text><Text>Education</Text>
      <Svg height="10" width="495"><Line x1="0" y1="5" x2="80" y2="5" strokeWidth={2} stroke="rgb(255,0,0)" /></Svg>
      <Text>I was educated at the "University of Life", at an early age from before I stirred. I was never shaken, unlike my Martini's, which must be "Shaken, not stirred."</Text>
      </View>
      
      <View style={styles.sectionTitle}><Text> </Text><Text>Work Experience</Text>
      <Svg height="10" width="495"><Line x1="0" y1="5" x2="140" y2="5" strokeWidth={2} stroke="rgb(0,255,0)" /></Svg>
      <Text>If I tell you, ... I dont know who you are, but  I will "Hunt you down". I will find you, and  ... "Hit you" with my License</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.sectionTitle}><Text> </Text><Text>Skills</Text>
      <Svg height="10" width="495"><Line x1="0" y1="5" x2="50" y2="5" strokeWidth={2} stroke="rgb(0,0,255)" /></Svg>
      <Text>Shooting Stars</Text>
      </View>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);

ReactPDF.render(doc);
```